# Struts2 request PUT parameter on body

Tags: java, struts2, httprequest, restful-url

i want to add parameter for HTTP Request PUT on the body, but i only can do like this

```
http://localhost:9996/Events/employee/{id}.json?name={name}
```

so how to put name on body?

here my controller

```
public class EmployeeController implements ModelDriven<Object>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
private String name;
private Object model;  
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();

//GET
public HttpHeaders index() { 
    model = employeeRepository.findAllEmployee(); 
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index").disableCaching();
}

// GET
public HttpHeaders show() { 
    model = employeeRepository.getEmployeeById(id);
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("show").disableCaching();
}

//POST
public HttpHeaders create() { 
    Integer empId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    Employee emp = new Employee(empId, name, "PQR");
    employeeRepository.addEmployee(emp);
    model = employeeRepository.findAllEmployee();
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("create").disableCaching();
}

//PUT
public HttpHeaders update() {  
    Integer empId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    Employee emp = new Employee(empId, name, "PQR");
    employeeRepository.updateEmployee(emp);
    model = employeeRepository.findAllEmployee();
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("update").disableCaching();
}

//DELETE
public HttpHeaders destroy() {   
    employeeRepository.deleteEmployee(id); 
    model = employeeRepository.findAllEmployee();
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("destroy").disableCaching();
}

public  String  getId()                 { return id; } 
public  void    setId(String id)        { this.id = id; } 
public  String  getName()               { return name; } 
public  void    setName(String name)    { this.name = name; } 
public  Object  getModel()              { return model; }
```

Comment: Where/How do you construct/use this url?

Comment: im using advance REST client in chrome extension

Comment: How S2 is related? Search how to use *advance REST client in chrome extension*.

Comment: yeah its related to S2, because when i add parameter "name" in body and i debug the source, parameter name is null

Comment: If it is in body why `name` in action should be set? You're using modeldriven, stop it or learn how to use it right.

Comment: because i want to update name value.
if im using wrong, please teach me how to use it, im still newbie to use REST with S2

Comment: Don't use modeldriven or retrieve name from the model.

Comment: @Lumanyun If you are using `ModelDriven` action the model should be created before parameters are populated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `JSON Interceptor` for your action and it should look something like the code below.

```
<package name="movies" extends="rest-default, json-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>

            <interceptor-stack name="jsonStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

<action name="movies" class="com.struts.movie.action.MoviesController">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"/>

            <result type="json">
                <!-- declarations for mappings from Request JSON Body goes here-->
                <param name="root">movie</param>
            </result>
        </action>

 </package>
```

***One catch over here is***, which I encountered, for a simple JSON Structure, like the one below,

```
{
    "hello": {
        "name":"kav"
    },
    "uid":"fdsfds"
}
```

where `hello` was intended to map to a `POJO class` `Hello.java` which was declared as a variable (`private Hello hello;` with its public getters and setters) in the controller. And `uid` was intended to map to a `String` variable `uid` declared in the controller (as `private String uid;` with its public getters and setters). This got mapped exactly without `hello` being mentioned in the `<result type="json">` tag, like `<param name="root">hello</param>`.

In the case of `movie`, it wasn't so, as it had nested objects, like the code below,

```
public class Movie{

    private String movieName;
    private String movieID;
    .... other variables
    private List<Actor> actors;
    private List<Review> reviews;

   // Declarations of constructor, Getters & Setters
}
```

Not sure why it happens so.